# How to get template source in php mustache engine

Tags: php, templates, mustache.php

I am trying to get a raw template that is already loaded by `Mustache_Engine`. On creation of the mustache object `Filesystem_Loader` instance is set up and pointing to the default directory.

```
$mustache = new Mustache_Engine( array(
    'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader( 'path-to-templates' )
) );
```

And later, for rendering the templates I use.

```
echo $mustache->render( 'template-name', $data );
```

The same template is used by `mustache.js` on server side, so i want to also print that template as inline script.

I could load the template from the filesystem manually with `file_get_contents`, but since that template is already loaded maybe there's a way to retrieve that from Mustache_Engine. Also, to use the `file_get_contents` i must use full path of the template and that just contradicts with the purpose of Mustache Template Loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging through the Mustache_Engine source, found the answer. `getLoader()` will get the current Mustache Template Loader instance, and `load()` function will load the template ( if is not already loaded ) and return it as string.

```
echo $mustache->getLoader()->load( 'template-name' );
```